# Boost python static linking MinGW

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to write a little wrapper for my library with boost python.
I use Cmake, mingw w64 and Python 3.4.

My Makefile seems like that:

```
# link python libs ...

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)  # focus on this line

# find boost and etc ...

add_library( some STATIC some.cpp ) # a maintainer library
add_library( wrap SHARED wrap.cpp )  # wrapper for python
target_link_libraries( wrap some ${Boost_LIBRARIES}  ${Python_LIBRARIES} )
# ...
```

That's rigth, build is successfuly, but in this case Boost links dynamically.

---

Supporse, I want a static link with Boost, I'm trying switch boost to static mode.

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
```

Link crashs with a lot of errors.

> wrap.cpp:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to _imp___ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE'
>
> wrap.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost6python9type_info4nameEv[__ZNK5boost6python9type_info4nameEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost6python6detail12gcc_demangleEPKc'

and stuff like that.

I built Boost with --build-type=complete key, and I have `libboost_python-mgw53-1_60.a` exactly. I confused.

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you manage to solve it?